# RMS amplitude of gaussian white noise

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, probability-theory

I would like to compute the RMS Amplitude, of a gaussian white noise signal.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mean = 0
std = 1.0

t = 100

def zv(t):
    return np.random.normal(mean, std, size = t)

def rms(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(zv(x)**2))

plt.plot(zv(t))

plt.plot(rms(t))
```

The plot of `zv(t)` works - but I don't know why the plot of `rms(t)` is just empty.

Do you have some comments?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zv(t)` returns a one dimensional array of size `t`. As a result, when you take the mean, it is a single value. You can verify this by printing out the value of `rms(t)`. If you want to create a plot along `t` for `rms`, you will need to generate multiple monte carlo samples. For example,

```
def zv(t):
    n = 1000
    return np.random.normal(mean, std, size = (n, t))

def rms(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(zv(x)**2, axis = 0))
```

Comment: Many thanks - now it works, but it looks very smilier to the plot of zv ... I wanted to investigate, if the rms amplitude is growing in proportion to sqrt(t) -- because the rms displacement of the Brownian motion is behaving like that

Comment: Maybe via summing up the random variables and evaluating the rms amplitude in every step?

Comment: Based on the approach that random numbers are being generated, they are independent at each time step, and I would not expect any change with `t`. You might need to provide a different random number generation that better represents your problem physics.

Comment: but the root mean square diosplacement of a random walk is proportional to the square root of timesteps?

Comment: That is a new and different question and beyond the scope of this problem. I can only tell you how it works in python based on the code sample you provided.